# Gmail API token limits

Tags: gmail-api

Can someone tell me if the tokens from Gmail are limited for applications or for users ?

For example I will create a SAAS where users will be able to log in with their Gmail account.
The tokens are limited for the website owner or for website users ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gmail's usage limits are applied to all requests made from your application, as well as per-user rate limits:

- **Daily Usage**:   1,000,000,000 quota units per day
- **Per User Rate Limit**:   250 quota units per user per second, *moving average* (allows short bursts)

For more information, see the docs: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota